# Datasource ${DS_PROMETHEUS} was not found" in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, datasource, dashboard

I'm reutilizing Grafana dashboards for different environments, deployed using Ansible. Grafana is a docker container working over Docker Swarm.
At some point it stopped working, not sure if after upgrading from Grafana 8.10.0 to Grafana 9.2.15.

[image: Charts don't show any info:]

If I try to export the dashboard with the option 'Export for sharing externally' the following json is shown:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Datasource ${prometheus} was not found"
  }
}
```

However, if I import the dashboard from the UI (left bar menu > dashboards > import) it works properly, I assume that it is because it asks me to select a datasource:

[image: Manual import]

How can I fix this issue with the datastore for the already deployed dashboards?

Comment: It is not clear how did you export/import (API/UI) and which Grafana versions were used for that export import. Grafana 7 / 9 have different dashboard model and this is causing a trouble.

Comment: @JanGaraj if you mean the panel plugins it wasn't an issue at all. I was able to update the version of all of them.
Could you please give some more detail about the dashboard model differentes between versions 7 and 9? 
Also is there any other relevant information that I could add  that may be of help?

Answer (score 5):

Define uid in datasources.yml:
**uid: prometheusdatasource**

Example:

```yaml
- name: Prometheus
    type: prometheus
    access: proxy
    url: http://prometheus:9090
    editable: false
    isDefault: false
    uid: prometheusdatasource
```

And update the dashborad config file:
**"datasource": "prometheusdatasource"**

Example:

```json
"panels": [
    {
      "collapsed": false,
      "datasource": "prometheusdatasource",
    }
]
```

Comment: In my case, I was only missing the `uid` definition in my `datasources.yml` file when using imported dashboards from https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using datasources yaml or you are running simple grafana container and you created a database connection from the graphical user interface, to find the uid of your database, simple navigate to

```
http://your-grafana-end-point/api/datasources
```

and you will find all your datasource autogenerated uid to pick up from.

When you import a panel json remember to change the datasource uid fields in the json you are copying from (example below)

```
"datasource": {
    "type": "prometheus",
    "uid": "c226b139-d9c1-429c-9984-559dd1c95216"
  },
```

to the uid you found from your api